# glpk err , import glpk module not found

Tags: python

I am not able to Run glpk module based programs, on python 2.7.1 , Mac OS platform.

I am not sure if glpk module is installed successfully.

kindly help me, i am new to this.

Comment: what "glpk module" did you install? Did you install PyGLPK? Use this instruction. http://pymprog.sourceforge.net/setup.html#how-to-setup-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Maybe GLPK is trying to load "**_glpkpi.so**" but it can not find it, try to append this library to your path

```
import sys    
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python-support/python-glpk/python2.7')
```

Of course, you have to change '/usr/lib/python-support/python-glpk/python2.7' for the correct path of your "**_glpkpi.so**" file

best