# Python: Why am I encountering this error with importing glpk on MacOSX?

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, glpk

I followed these steps and got my first error:

```
wget http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~jpp/code/python-glpk/python-glpk_0.4.43.orig.tar.gz
tar -xzf python-glpk_0.4.43.orig.tar.gz
cd python-glpk-0.4.43/src/
sudo make install
```

I got this error:

```
make -C swig all
make[1]: pyversions: Command not found
gcc -Wall -c -fPIC glpkpi_wrap.c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/lib//config
glpkpi_wrap.c:130:11: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
# include <Python.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [glpkpi_wrap.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then I linked to the python by changing the Python version or let's say section:
inside `swig/Makefile`

changed

```
PYVERS := $(shell pyversions -d)
```

to

```
PYVERS := "Python 2.7.6"
```

which is my python version

```
make -C swig all
swig -python  glpkpi.i
./glpk.h:916: Warning 314: 'in' is a python keyword, renaming to '_in'
sed -i 's/:in /:_in /g' glpkpi.py
sed: 1: "glpkpi.py": extra characters at the end of g command
make[1]: *** [glpkpi.py] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now when I run `python test.py` inside the examples folder, it just crashes and says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glpk/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from glpk_parser import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glpk/glpk_parser.py", line 352, in <module>
    yacc.yacc(write_tables=0, debug=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 3244, in yacc
    read_signature = lr.read_table(tabmodule)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 1967, in read_table
    if parsetab._tabversion != __tabversion__:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_tabversion'
```

I tried the following tutorials:
[Build and install from source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Python)

then I tried

[Installing-Python-glpk Tutorial](http://blog.ducky.io/python/2013/07/01/Installing-Python-glpk/)

Something is just not right, what step am I missing that is causing the

```
import glpk
```

to fail?

I tried brew installation as well, no luck! I have included my Python path as well, still no help.

Ah and lastly I tried this:

```
import sys    

sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/glpk/')
```

still no luck! Last step was inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564891/539075)

Comment: Why is this tagged C ?

Comment: You don't have the python C headers (`python-dev` package on linux), which created your compilation errors.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I did include C, but most probably because the glpk packages are in C and the compiler is included in the process.

Comment: @Antoine This error is on a OS X Yosemite 10.10.4, should I still install the ```python-dev``` libraries or not needed?

Comment: @Antoine I have the headers here:
```python-config --include``` 

```-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7```

Comment: If you have a `Python.h` header file in this folder, then you already have the development dependencies for python ans your action on PYVERS solved the header issue.  Your next error seems to come from the `ply` package (or its usage from glpk). Wich version of ply did you install?

Comment: @Antoine thanks for the follow up, I have ```Version: 3.6``` for ply, and I'm not necessarily sure if creating a link, like a symblink would help with the ```Python.h```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I tried to reproduce your problem and went through the same errors,
I managed to make it work by changing the version of `ply` from *3.6* to *3.4*.

Note that I had an error with the `glpk` library and had to downgrade it to *4.43*

Comment: Thanks I will mark this as an answer, but I got another series of errors.  This ```glpk``` is a just broken and bad! No idea why isn't there an alternate dependency that this awful one.

Comment: Fixed my problem. You rock @Antoine

Comment: Fixed my problem. Thank you. Got another error, though. " undefined symbol: _glp_lpx_simplex"