# python-glpk installation fix

Tags: python, anaconda, glpk

I am trying to install GLPK python module to work on linear programming from a different angle but I am not getting it right. can some one tell me what is it that I am missing?

Here is the error in detail:

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import glpk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glpk/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from glpk_parser import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/glpk/glpk_parser.py", line 352, in <module>
yacc.yacc(write_tables=0, debug=0)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 3244, in yacc
read_signature = lr.read_table(tabmodule)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 1967, in read_table
if parsetab._tabversion != __tabversion__:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_tabversion'
```

I followed instructions as shown in the [link](http://blog.ducky.io/python/2013/07/01/Installing-Python-glpk/)

I searched the web for some solutions and some solutions said that there must be a version mismatch, but I am not sure if that is the same for me as well.

I also installed glpk version 4.35 with the following instructions :

Tar -xvf [filename]
./configure 
Make 
Make install 
This will install
Glpsol --help 
Once installed

[Though I am not sure of there is a connection made]

can someone please help me out?

Comment: Think you got the same error as in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717102/python-why-am-i-encountering-this-error-with-importing-glpk-on-macosx) - try the suggested solution. BTW. why you are using the old glpk version 4.35?

Comment: @PaulG. I did go through the same link in the afternoon, that's when I considered mismatched versions of the libraries in question after seeing the answers. So not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

So I can confirm that this is a version mismatch. Since python glpk is not that well maintained it became a little incompatible with ply.

What is happening here is that ply is getting initialized without any specific written model. It will automatically load `parsetab.py` which lacks the needed attribute `_tabversion`.

So you can probably add a `_tabversion = '3.10'` (newest ply version) to parsetab, which should create the needed attribute. On the other hand you can use the ply version which was used during development of python glpk (old 3.4 version) which has some additional compatibility paths for those old module files.

Last option would be to use a better maintained implementation of glpk-bindings for python (at University we used glpk via pyomo in python for our students)